# Not Able to start Deployer Service after Sdl Web 8.5 CME installation

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion, installation, deployerservice

I have installed SDL web 8.5 on a single machine as mentioned here https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-8789A353-267D-4466-9A6D-4CF6709E4E88&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-26992293-7D88-46D7-937F-5EBBA1DA3ABF.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-8789A353-267D-4466-9A6D-4CF6709E4E88

But the Deployer service is not getting started.  When I try to start it manually, it says "SOME SERVICES STOP AUTOMATICALLY IF THEY ARE NOT IN USE BY OTHER SERVICES OR PROGRAMS". I can see Web Capabilities are added as roles in Cd_Storage file of Discovery Service :

```
<Role Name="TokenServiceCapability" Url="http://10.0.1.5:8082/token.svc"/>
      <Role Name="WebCapability"/>
</Roles>
```

I can See Deployer Service set as Local System Account for logon, which should be correct.

[image]

Note: I have ran `.\quickinstall.ps1 -enable-discovery -enable-context -enable-deployer-combined -enable-preview -enable-session -auto-register -discovery-url http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc`

`-auto-register` switch is on, also `java -jar discovery-registration.jar update` command executed

Only thing I noticed that after running quick install PowerShell with auto-register on, I didn't see Web Capabilities added in Cd_Storage file, I added it manually as mentioned in the doc as well.

Is it a correct sequence, or do I need to run the quick install again as web capabilities are added later?

Comment: I dont know how but it seems Restart Of the CME Server cause it work, Now i can start the deployer service but pubishing stucks in Waiting for Publishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should expect there to be any dependency between the CME and the deployer service. In normal circumstances, you would be expecting them to run on entirely separate servers, with the only connection being that the transport service talks to the deployer endpoint.

If you encounter a problem when running them on the same server, then a possible cause for problems is contention over some resource or other. So you could check whether you've configured the two services on the same port, for example.

In your comment you mention that publishing is stuck in Waiting for Publisher. Assuming that your items are the only items in the queue, the usual cause for this is that the publisher service isn't running.

In general with this kind of work, the most helpful source of information is logging. So make sure the appropriate logging level is set (presumably DEBUG in this situation) and read the logs.